# U-blox Sara R410 Newtork registration as roaming (CREG: 1,5) but not registers as Home network (CREG:: 1,1)

Tags: at-command, cellular-network, roaming

I am developing a custom firmware for a device using U-Blox SARA R410M-02B-01. I am using Hologram SIM card activated for global coverage and I am based on Spain. I am trying to register to a network, but I am unable to connect to it, the command `AT+CREG`:

`+CREG: 1,0`

seems to indicate `0` stat, which according to the AT commands manual indicates not register, neither looking for a network.

[image]

I tried to set up the `USVCDOMAIN` to `CS/PS` as this:

`AT+USVCDOMAIN=2,0,1`

to enable both Circuit Switch (CS) and Packet Switch(PS) service domains, and although it worked and make a registration, it registrered the network as roaming, because when I do `CREG` again after enable CS service domain, I receive:

`+CREG: 1,5`

which indicates registered as roaming. The weirdest thing, is that even when CREG states no Network Registration, I have network access through the SARA modem.

In addition to the above, the whole time, the commmand `+CGATT` seems to indicate that it is registered to Packet Switched services.

Thanks in advance.